# fs Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, runtime-error

I'm getting "Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read" after trying to read the content of a .json. This is how I'm trying to access the file. I'm using the FileSystem of node js.

```
fs.readFile( path, ( err, fileData) => {

                if (err) {

                    throw err;
                }
                else {

                    return fileData;
                }
            });
```

While debugging I can see that the error is thrown before the if statement.

Any idea?

Comment: That error sounds like your `path` is a directory, not a file.  You need to pass a path that points to a file to `fs.readFile()`.  You should also know that neither `throw err` or `return fileData` are going to do anything useful.  That returns data back into the file system code who called your callback, not back to the caller of your parent function.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the path to the file is not the right one, make sure the path of your file looks like the one that appears in the following code:

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE/File_Name.json', (err, fileData) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } else {
        console.log(JSON.parse(fileData));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this error because it can not read my folder. so I trust read files and it working